# Vuex state array turning an proxy object when it is mutated

Tags: vue.js, vuex, state-management

I develop a project which gets datas from database. I use Vuex for state management.

**Vuex Store File**

```js
const store = createStore({
    state: {
        notUser: {
            name: "",
            email: '',
            password: ''
        },
        user: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            messages: [],
            about: '',
            place: '',
            age: '',
            role: '',
            blocked: false
        },
        problem: {
            title: '',
            content: ''
        },
        problems: [],
        errorMessage: {
            error: false,
            message: '',
            success: false
        },

    },
    mutations: {
        errorHandler(state, error) {
            state.errorMessage.error = true
            state.errorMessage.message = error.response.data.message
        },
        defineUser(state, req) {
            state.user = req.data.user
            console.log(state.user)
        },
        getProblems(state, problems) {
            state.problems = problems
            console.log(state.problems)
        }
    },
    actions: {
        register({ commit }, notUser) {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register',
                data: notUser,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                  }
              })
              .then(res => {
                this.state.errorMessage.success = true
                  console.log(res.data.data.user)
              })
              .catch(err => {
                this.state.errorMessage.success = false
                console.log(err.response)
                commit('errorHandler', err)
              })
        },
        userLogin({commit}, notUser) {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login',
                data: notUser,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                  }
              })
              .then(res => {
                this.state.user = res.data.data.user
                this.state.errorMessage.success = true
                console.log(this.state.user)
              })
              .catch(err => {
                this.state.errorMessage.success = false
                console.log(err.response)
                commit('errorHandler', err)
              })
        },
        checkUser({commit}, access_token) {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/VpW02cG0W2vGeGXs8DdLIq3dQ62qMd0',
                data: access_token,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                  }
              })
              .then(res => {
                  console.log(res)
                  commit('defineUser', res)
                return true
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err.response)
                commit('errorHandler', err)
                return false
              })
        },
        sendProblem({commit}, problem) {
            axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/problem/add',
                data: problem,
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                  }
              })
              .then(res => {
                  console.log(res)
                return true
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err.response)
                commit('errorHandler', err)
                return false
              })
        },
        getAllProblems({commit}) {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/problem/getall',
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json"
                  }
              })
              .then(res => {
                  commit('getProblems', res.data.data)
                return true
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err.response)
                commit('errorHandler', err)
                return false
              })
        }

        // registerUser({commit}, user) {
        //     commit('register', user)
        // }
    },
```

**Vue Component: Where Vuex store is being used**

```js
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["user", 'problems'])
  },
  mounted() {
      return this.getAll()
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getAllProblems']),
    goToAdd() {
      this.$router.push('/add')
    },
    async getAll() {
        this.getAllProblems()
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I try to request with getAllProblems action, it should mutate problems variable with getProblems(). Actually it does. But after problems variable changes, it turns something a proxy object. Here are images:

Here is an image of proxy object: [image: turned proxy object]

The original data coming from database: [image: original data]

---

Thanks for comment of @Hasan Hasanova
Okay got it. I called api before website is mounted and used function to get variables from store. The other problem was happened because of using wrong syntax of v-for. Here is the code:

```
computed: {
    allProblems() { // this is the problems array that i was trying to get
      return this.$store.state.allProblems
    },
    loader() {
      return this.allProblems == null ? true : false
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getAllProblems', {root: true})
    
  },
```

And here is the template code :

```
<div v-if="allProblems.length > 0" class="middle-side">
        <div v-for="(problem) in allProblems" :key="problem.id" class="card">
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'ProblemDetail', params: { id: problem._id, slug: problem.slug }}">
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="card-header-title">
                <div class="user-image">
                  <img src="../../assets/problem.png" />
                </div>
                <span class="user-name">{{ problem.user.name }}</span>
              </div>

...
```

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as yours, but I solved it first by converting it before the getter's return, converting it to JSON to string, and converting a string to JSON again before returning it.

```
const str = JSON.stringify(data)
return  JSON.parse(str)
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I wish that I had a better way of solving my issue. When I first stored my object in vuex store, it was not a proxy object, then when I retrieve it, it is a proxy object, then when I store the updated object, it stores a proxy object, breaking my flow.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `mapActions` to call the action. Then get your data via state, instead of returning the function, since the action is calling a mutation via `commit`.

---

```js
  computed: {
    // you have access to `problems` in the template. Use `v-if` before you `v-for` over the array of problems.
    ...mapState(["user", 'problems'])
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getAllProblems();
  },
  methods: {
    // ...mapActions(['getAllProblems']),
    goToAdd() {
      this.$router.push('/add')
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. But nothing changes when i use the getAllProblems() with ...mapActions . It still sends proxy object.

Comment: You should access the state and not rely on action to return your value.

Comment: I edited my code something like https://i.ibb.co/LRQJMJS/Screenshot-from-2020-11-09-17-37-04.png . Is it true? And now it gives an error: https://i.ibb.co/WVkn6fW/untitled-3.png  Sorry I couldn't catch exactly what are you trying to tell me.

Comment: Could you show a `console.log()` response that the api request returns, or maybe a REST client you used. Just double check if `user` actually exists on the `problems > item` object.

Comment: Here it is: https://i.imgur.com/1x9BzEu.png I return res.data.data to get user from home component

Comment: You should check: `v-if="problems.length > 1"`

Comment: Now it doesn't show the content but in console.log it still shows response, problems varialble (as a Proxy object shown in the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXr2b.png) and same error that i just shared with you: https://i.ibb.co/WVkn6fW/untitled-3.png

Comment: If you could push this code to github or something, I can play with it on my machine, and debug it for you. I feel like it is a silly problem we can't just identify. (Programming is 90% debugging and 10% coding)

Comment: I have started playing with Vue 3 and Vuex 4. I hit the exact same thing. I am not sure if this is intended behavior or not. But when I return my state object and access it in the template everything works as expected. @oldner your github link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that happens during the passing of res.data.data to mutations. So if you're expecting a single row result set you should do like:

```
POPULATE_THIS_STATE_VAR(state, data) {
    state.thisStateVar = data[0]
}
```

... and if you're expecting an array of objects to the result set like what you have, you could do like:

```
POPULATE_THIS_STATE_VAR(state, data) {
     if (data) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              state.thisStateVar .push(data[i])
          }
     }
}
```